# How to select one option and display the results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application very simple with a dropdown select menu of different categories.. Each category has a set of Recipes. So if you click on Italian in the select, I'd like to display an array of the Italian recipes.

The categories and Recipes are created with Active Admin.

The front end select menu looks as follows:

```
<select class="styled email-input">
    <% @category.each do |category| %>
      <option><%= category.name %></option>
    <% end %>
    </select>
```

The category belongs to the Recipe, and the Recipe has many categories.

All the content is being displayed on the landing#index page, landing_controller.rb:

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = Category.all
  end
end
```

So again, when a user clicks a category how do I then display the recipes associated with that category in the view?

**Update error:**

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column recipes.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  WHERE "recipes"."category_id...
                                               ^
: SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes"  WHERE "recipes"."category_id" = '2'
```

**Update 2 models:**

Recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  belongs_to :category

  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to display it in the view without reloading the page you would need to write javascript for it. Otherwise, you would pass the selected option as a param to the index action and reload the whole page something like this (I'm making assumptions about a few things like the categories model having a name attribute):

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @category = Category.all
    @recipes = Recipes.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
  end
end
```

Then your view could be something like this:

```
<%= form_tag landing_index_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag "category_id", options_for_select(@category.map{ |category| [category.name, category.id] }, selected: params["category_id"])) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and maybe underneath it you can display relevant recipes like:

```
<% if @recipes %>
  <% @recipes.each do ...%>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A reload is fine for now, care to provide an example of how to pass the selected option as a param to the index action? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! ALthough I'm getting an error :(. I've updated the original post with it. I know that Categories have recipe_id's but do Recipes's have category_id's? Categories belong_to recipes, and recipes have_many categories.

Comment: Do you have the `belongs_to category` in your migration for your recipe table?

Comment: Look at section 3.3 of [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and section 2.1